# PHP Count Number of True Values in a Boolean Array

Tags: php, arrays, if-statement, count, associative-array

I have an associative array in which I need to count the number of boolean true values within.

The end result is to create an if statement in which would return true when only one true value exists within the array. It would need to return false if there are more then one true values within the array, or if there are no true values within the array.

I know the best route would be to use count and in_array in some form. I'm not sure this would work, just off the top of my head but even if it does, is this the best way?

```
$array(a->true,b->false,c->true)    

if (count(in_array(true,$array,true)) == 1)
{
    return true
}
else
{
    return false
}
```

Answer (score 52, accepted):

I would use array_filter.

```
$array = array(true, true, false, false);
echo count(array_filter($array));
//outputs: 2
```

[Array_filter](http://www.php.net/array_filter) will remove values that are false-y (value == false). Then just get a count. If you need to filter based on some special value, like if you are looking for a specific value, array_filter accepts an optional second parameter that is a function you can define to return whether a value is true (not filtered) or false (filtered out).

Answer (score 14):

Since TRUE is casted to 1 and FALSE is casted to 0. You can also use [array_sum](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-sum.php)

```
$array = array('a'=>true,'b'=>false,'c'=>true);
if(array_sum($array) == 1) {
    //one and only one true in the array
}
```

From the [doc](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php#language.types.integer.casting) : "FALSE will yield 0 (zero), and TRUE will yield 1 (one)."

Comment: This would have worked just as well, thanks for the provision!

Comment: This is actually a pretty clever solution. Kudos!

Answer (score 3):

Try this approach :

```
<?php
$array = array(1, "hello", 1, "world", "hello");
print_r(array_count_values($array));
?>
```

Result :

```
Array
(
   [1] => 2
   [hello] => 2
   [world] => 1
)
```

[Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php)

Comment: This works for strings/integers, however they are looking for boolean values. So this will throw an E_WARNING for every element not a string/int. Example: http://codepad.viper-7.com/zPTF0U

Answer (score 0):

like this?

```
$trues = 0;
foreach((array)$array as $arr) {
   $trues += ($arr ? 1 : 0);
}
return ($trues==1);
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using [array_count_values](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) to get an array with everything counted? Then check how many true's there are?