# Count number of variables if set to 'yes'

Tags: php, count

I'm trying to count the number of variables that are set to 'yes' using PHP and then output the count.

So for example, I have the following variables:

```
$facebook = $params->get('facebook');
$twitter = $params->get('twitter');
$email = $params->get('email');
$pinterest = $params->get('pinterest');
$google = $params->get('google');
```

and if they're all set to 'yes', then there would be a count of 5, using this method:

```
<?php
    $social = array('facebook', 'twitter', 'email', 'pinterest', 'google');
    echo count($social); // output 5
?>
```

However, if some are set to 'no' how can I then count all of the ones which are set to 'yes'?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) then `count`.

```
$social = array('facebook', 'twitter', 'email', 'pinterest', 'google');
$count = count(array_filter($social, function($val) use ($params) {
  return $params->get($val) === 'yes';
}));
```

Comment: @xdazz can u explain this `function($val) use ($params)`

Answer (score 0):

Better add them to array

```
$vars['facebook'] = $params->get('facebook');
$vars['twitter'] = $params->get('twitter');
$vars['email'] = $params->get('email');
$vars['pinterest'] = $params->get('pinterest');
$vars['google'] = $params->get('google');
```

Than loop that array

```
$count = 0;
foreach ($vars as $var) {
    $count += strtolower($var) == 'yes' ? 1 : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set the variables of the various social `true` if they are equal to `'yes'`, `false` otherwise, then just sum them.

```
$facebook  = ( $params->get('Facebook')  == 'yes');
$twitter   = ( $params->get('twitter')   == 'yes');
$email     = ( $params->get('email')     == 'yes');
$pinterest = ( $params->get('pinterest') == 'yes');
$google    = ( $params->get('google')    == 'yes');

$count = $facebook + $twitter + $email + $pinterest + $google;
```

Or, if you want to use an array, set the var as before and then you can look at this answer: [PHP Count Number of True Values in a Boolean Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428635/php-count-number-of-true-values-in-a-boolean-array)

Answer (score 0):

Well a simple method would be to do a loop and then check each of the values...

```
$true = 0; //The count...
foreach ($social as $value) {
    if ($value = "yes") { $true++; } //Checks each value if 'yes', increases count...
}
echo $true; //Shows the count...
```