# How can I count true and false values in my PHP array?

Tags: php

I'm developing a plugin which does API calls. As a result I'm filling an array with boolean values for success and false.

When my calls are done (multiple calls possible), I want to output a message how many calls were successful and how many failed. This sounds like a simple task, but I have no idea how to do a simple counting.

I've found this question here which fits the most but still misses the false counting part:

[PHP Count Number of True Values in a Boolean Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16428635/php-count-number-of-true-values-in-a-boolean-array)

Do you have any idea how I can get this done a simple way?

This is an example array:

```
$result = [
    true,
    false,
    false,
    true,
    true,
    true
];

$successful_calls_count = count($result)....
$failed_calls_count = count($result)....
```

Comment: Wouldn't the false count be the total entries in the original array minus the true count.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make the second step pretty easily if you just deduct the successful count from the overall count.

```
$successful = count(array_filter($array));
$failed = count($array) - $successful;
```

Comment: Now I feel stupid - I always think too complicated. Thanks for your answer!

Answer (score 1):

```
 $successful = count(array_filter($array));
 $failed = count(array_filter($array, function ($v) {return !$v;} ));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`array_count_values()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) and [`array_map()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-map.php).

```
$result = [
    true,
    false,
    false,
    true,
    true,
    true
];

//array_map converts BOOL values to ints (0 for false, 1 for true)
//array_count_values counts the amount of each value in an array
$counts = array_count_values(
    array_map('intval', $result)
);

$successful = $counts[1];
$failed = $counts[0];
```